# React Formik Array Field Error Uncontrolled Inputs changing to controlled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, formik

I am developing a React frontend to send form data back to my API. I have decided to use formik to create the required forms for my app. While testing the array field and trying to add validation errors only at the in question array element input field. I have run into this error.

Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info:

I have successfully implemented my form and errors for other fields except the array field, so I tried to add the ErrorMessage tag with the correct array element index as the name and this is when the error showed its fangs first.

Here is my component code:

I tried to dig into the error and find the solution my self, but all the other stack overflow answers I saw discussing this error were too complicated for me to understand. If anyone can help would be much appreciated also if you have any tips on how I could clean up this code I'll take it its not the prettiest.

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {Formik, Form, Field, FieldArray, ErrorMessage} from 'formik'
import * as Yup from 'yup'
const Sign = () => {
    const ciscoDomainRegex = new RegExp('.*\.cisco\.com')
    const SignSchema = Yup.object({
        hostname:Yup.string().matches(ciscoDomainRegex, 'Hostname Must Be A Cisco Domain').required('required'),
        sans:Yup.array().of(Yup.string().matches(ciscoDomainRegex)),
        csr:Yup.mixed()
    })

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const showError = (errors, field)=>{
        switch (field){
            case 'hostname':
                return <p>{errors.hostname}</p>
            case 'sans':
                return <p>{errors.sans}</p>
            case 'csr':
                return <p>{errors.csr}</p>
            default:
                return false
        }
    }

    return ( 
    <div>
        Sign Page
        <Formik
        initialValues={{
            hostname:'',
            sans:[''],
            csr:null
        }}
        validationSchema={SignSchema}
        onSubmit={(values)=>console.log(values)}
        >
            {({errors, touched, setFieldValue})=>{
                return(
            <Form className="form-center">
                <Field className="form-control mt-1" name='hostname' placeholder="Enter Hostname"/>
                {/* {errors && touched.hostname ? showError(errors, 'hostname') : null} */}
                <ErrorMessage name="hostname"/>
                <FieldArray  name="sans" placeholder='Enter Sans'>
                    {({push, remove, form})=>{
                        const {sans} = form.values
                        return (
                            <div>
                                {
                                    sans.map((san, i)=>{
                                        return (
                                            <div className="input-group" key={i}>
                                                <Field className="form-control mt-1" name={`sans${i}`} placeholder="Enter San"/>
                                                {/* {errors && touched.sans ? showError(errors, 'sans') : null} */}
                                                <ErrorMessage name={`sans${i}`}/>
                                                <div className="input-group-append">
                                                    <button className="btn btn-secondary float-end" type="button" onClick={()=>remove(i)}>-</button>
                                                    <button className="btn btn-secondary" type="button" onClick={()=>push('')}>+</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        )
                                    })
                                }
                            </div>
                            )        
                    }}
                </FieldArray>
                <input className="form-control mt-1" type="file" name='csr' onChange={(e)=>setFieldValue('csr',e.currentTarget.files[0])}/>
                {errors && console.log(errors)}
                <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </Form>
             )
            }}
        </Formik>
    </div>
     );
}
 
export default Sign;
```

Comment: The name of the field should be either `sans[${i}]` or `sans.${i}` and not `sans${i}`

Comment: Thank you I actually just figured it out preciate it tho

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong field name for each of the fields that will be added dynamucally.

Each field name should be name[index] like so...

<Field name={`san[$(index)]`/>

or u can as well use the dot notation to reference the particular field in the field array

PS: don't forget to use backticks